# C# .NET Core - How to load a razor page through an "onlick" event?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to load a "Details" page for a row of data in a table using the `onclick` event of the specific table row.

I am essentially trying to implement the following to the `onclick` but cant seem to get the syntax right as i need to specify an area:

```
 <a asp-area="Events" asp-page="/Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID"></a>
```

My table is as follows so far:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Events)
{
  <tr onclick="......">
      <td>@item.FirstName</td>
      <td>@item.LastName</td>
      <td>@item.PersonType.Name</td>
      <td>@item.Arrived</td>
      <td>@item.Departed</td>
      <td>@item.Duration</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
<tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Page("Details", new { id = item.ID, area = "Events" }))'">
```

Confirm that you have `Details` page in `Events` area .